# How can I format my output to be the same as the example?

Tags: python-3.x, format

I dont know how to justify my output format to be the as example shown. The first image is my output and the second image is the example.

```
for x in range(0,count):
     print(str(x+1).rjust(1),team[x].rjust(2),str(conference[x]).rjust(3),str(points[x]).rjust(4),str(goals[x]).rjust(5))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What language are you using? Please provide code examples.

Comment: i am using python3

Comment: @XieWeilun indent your code

Answer (score 0):

If you put "\t" in the print statement it is the same as tab. You should be able to get it how you want with "\t".